# Data recovery from file collections

Tags: data-recovery, forensics

I am presently working as a summer intern.

My first objective is, given a collection of files, recover and identify the file types present in it.

To download sample pseudo-forensics data I have been using: [Digital Corpora](http://digitalcorpora.org/)

To recover files I have been using '[The Sleuthkit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/)' but this does not seem to do the work as I always get error messages regarding the format of the data being used.

It would be great to get suggestions/links to tutorials or software which help in recovering data.

I am also looking forward to links to download psuedo forensic data similar to the one above.

Specifically, I would like to recover all data that are in text formats(word,pdf,emails,html... etc) then unify it into one single file in text format and then use natural language processing to determine places the person was associated with. I have some ideas with respect the natural language processing aspect of the problem but need help with respect to data recovery. How best to do this task.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple free programs intended for data recovery and carving that are highly effective and reliable. I'd recommend trying out:

- **foremost** - http://foremost.sourceforge.net/,
- **scalpel** - https://github.com/machn1k/Scalpel-2.0
- **PhotoRec** - http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Commercial tools are far easier to operate but not necessarily generate as good output as those.

Comment: This is an old answer that popped up in a review queue, & you were attempting to answer a question that should have been closed as off-topic.  For future reference, just pointing to a product isn't considered a good answer because it doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.